# JavaScript JSONP Request Error -- Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Tags: javascript, json, jsonp

I'm developing something locally and running `npm`.

I tried using JavaScript to run a `jsonp` request on the api to get some data back.

I keep getting the same error and everything looks fine, although not sure what the problem is. Any help is appreciated.

**Error Message:** `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`

**Note: I do not want to use jQuery for this at all**

Here's my jsonp funciton

```
function jsonp(url, callback) {
   var script = document.createElement("script");
   script.src = url
   document.body.appendChild(script);
}

jsonp('/api/nav.json', function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

JSON File

```
{
   "items":[
      {
         "label":"Home",
         "url":"#/home",
         "items":[

         ]
      },
      {
         "label":"About",
         "url":"#/about",
         "items":[
            {
               "label":"What I eat",
               "url":"#/about/what-i-eat"
            },
            {
               "label":"How I Play",
               "url":"#/about/how-i-play"
            },
         ]
      },
      {
         "label":"Project",
         "url":"#/project",
         "items":[
         ]
      },
      {
         "label":"Ideas",
         "url":"#/ideas",
         "items":[
            {
               "label":"Cookies Club",
               "url":"#/ideas/cookies-club"
            },
            {
               "label":"Footie Boots",
               "url":"#/ideas/footie-boots"
            },
            {
               "label":"Books",
               "url":"#/ideas/books"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "label":"Contact",
         "url":"#/contact",
         "items":[
            {
               "label":"Email",
               "url":"#/contact/email"
            },
            {
               "label":"Phone",
               "url":"#/contact/phone"
            },
            {
               "label":"Snail Mail",
               "url":"#/contact/snail-mail"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: A JSON response is not the same as a JSONP response. If your server is emitting the JSON you've listed then it's not JSONP

Comment: It's a json file. You can still make a jsonp request can't you?

Comment: @patrick no, you need to make a regular json request.

Comment: @m59 care to explain? I'm genuinely curious. I thought JSONP was strictly just a way to call for cross-site requests. At least it's that in jQuery.

Comment: @patrick Yes, but JSONP is not the same as JSON. The server has to support it. If they were identical, JSONP would be redundant, after all. This will probably explain it ok https://niryariv.wordpress.com/2009/05/05/jsonp-quickly/ (just google, bro!)

Comment: @m59 I have been googling! I know the file exists, since its local which is why its odd i'm getting the error. I try adding a callback to it, but then I got a 404 that the file doesn't exist.

I know I can do an XMLHttpRequest for the data but that isn't the same.

Comment: @patrick seems like you didn't read the article. The server has to support JSONP, by responding with a function that wraps the data.

Comment: JSON: `{"foo": "bar"}` ... JSONP: `someGlobalFunc({"foo": "bar"})`

Comment: JSONP is nothing but including a JavaScript script dynamically (as you seem to know). Hence the data sent from the server must be valid JavaScript. If you just paste `{"items": "bar"}` into the console, you will notice that JSON by itself is not valid JavaScript (and even if it were, you would not be able to get a reference to the data)).

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a function that will be called by the newly loaded script. A jsonp return is live code to be run immediately, not a dead object like traditional json.

This code below works and is tested.

So something like this, where the callback is named theData:

```
function jsonp(url, callback) {
   var script = document.createElement("script");
   script.src = url
   document.body.appendChild(script);
}


theData = function(data){
    console.log(data);
}
jsonp('ok.js?callBack=theData');
```

Jquery creates the call back for you by passing it to the jsonp loader and adding the function to Window temporarily and then removing it after its been called just after sending it to the jsonp success function. In your case you can do the same, but I thought this simpler example would show the basics.

Then use PHP or the like to wrap the JSON in a function call. In PHP you  can fetch the name of the function with $GET['callback'] and use that string as the function name of the function in which to wrap your data. Once the script is loaded it will attempt to run "theData," in this case which is a function available on Window. This will allow you to load local files if the html is also local, and allow you to open data from a different domain. So the output from the server is:

```
theData({ "items":[
      {
         "label":"Home",
         "url":"#/home",
         "items":[

         ]
      },
      {
         "label":"About",
         "url":"#/about",
         "items":[
            {
               "label":"What I eat",
               "url":"#/about/what-i-eat"
            },
            {
               "label":"How I Play",
               "url":"#/about/how-i-play"
            },
         ]
      },
      {
         "label":"Project",
         "url":"#/project",
         "items":[
         ]
      },
      {
         "label":"Ideas",
         "url":"#/ideas",
         "items":[
            {
               "label":"Cookies Club",
               "url":"#/ideas/cookies-club"
            },
            {
               "label":"Footie Boots",
               "url":"#/ideas/footie-boots"
            },
            {
               "label":"Books",
               "url":"#/ideas/books"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "label":"Contact",
         "url":"#/contact",
         "items":[
            {
               "label":"Email",
               "url":"#/contact/email"
            },
            {
               "label":"Phone",
               "url":"#/contact/phone"
            },
            {
               "label":"Snail Mail",
               "url":"#/contact/snail-mail"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
})
```